# Riemann non-integrability on sub-interval $[c,d] \subset [a,b]$ implies Riemann non-integrability on interval $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Problem is the following:

$\displaystyle\qquad f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(1/x) & \text{if } x  \text{ is irrational} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise } \end{cases}$

Prove that $f(x)$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

My approach:

I can show that for  a sub-interval $I_{1} = [2/\pi,1]$,

$\displaystyle \qquad U(I_{1},f)-L(I_{1},f) > \sin(1)\ (1-\frac{\pi}{2}\ )$

But i could not find any property which imply that if $I_{1}$ is not Riemann integrable then interval $A=[0,1]$ is also not Riemann integrable.

Comment: This follows directly from Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability, if this is available to you.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? From a Riemann upper/lower sum into $[a,b]$ you can get a Riemann upper/lower sum into $[c,d]$. Now, if you can find a lower and an upper Riemann sum whose difference is arbitrarily small, it will be arbitrarily small on any subinterval.

Comment: Yes thats right. I tried finding similar examples but did not come across any. So it was just to confirm as i am just a beginner in this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: note that for any propositions $A$ and $B$ it holds that
$$
(A\implies B)\iff (\lnot B\implies \lnot A)
$$
Therefore proving that
$$
\int_c^d f(x)\,\mathrm d x\text{ doesn't exists }\implies \int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x\text{  doesn't exists}
$$
for $[c,d]\subset [a,b]$, is equivalent to show that
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x\text{ exists }\implies \int_c^d f(x)\,\mathrm d x\text{ exists }
$$
what could be easier to prove. The above strategy is named as **proof by contraposition** because the contrapositive of the implication $A\implies B$ is $\lnot B\implies \lnot A$.

For your question probably is the same to prove the statement directly or the contrapositive statement, however it is a very useful technique to remember to prove things

Comment: perfect! This is the exact thing i am looking for.